# JsDoc type union on @returns attribute

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

This example is probably a weird pattern and I might change it anyway, but that lead me to wonder if it was possible to define a union type on the `@returns` attribute of JsDoc. Here is the example to make it more explicit :

```js
  function isInputValid(email: string, password: string): string | void {
    /**
     * Verify user email and password inputs.
     * @param {string} email - The user email input.
     * @param {string} password - The user password input.
     * @returns {boolean | void} The invalid user input.
     */
    if (!validEmail(email)) {
      return email;
    }

    if (!validPassword(password)) {
      return password;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Refer to the JSDoc documentation on @return here](https://jsdoc.app/tags-returns.html).

You were close, just missing some brackets `()`.

```
/**
 * Verify user email and password inputs.
 * @param {string} email - The user email input.
 * @param {string} password - The user password input.
 * @returns {(boolean|void)} The invalid user input.
 */
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I skimmed through that doc too fast, did not caught it. Thanks.

Comment: No worries at all. Glad to help.